# Fill angularjs template with a http request?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In below code How can I fill template with result of a $http request?
for example I want to use result of:

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.login = function () {
    $http.post("login", {password: $scope.password, username: $scope.username}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // data is result with html format 
        console.log("successfully logged to login")
        });
    };
}
```

in the below template attribute

```
angular.module(......).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {controller: LoginCtrl, template: ?? {

        }
```

Comment: Where is the $http call defined?

Comment: Can you explain the scenario a little. Why is login trying to return html, instead it can return success and failure and the template url should be predefined for success and failure.

Answer (score 0):

You basically bind the value of `$scope.login` in your template, using `{{login}}`. But in your case, `login` is a function that doesn't return a value. So, make it return a value, like this:

```js
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.login = function() {
    $http.post("login", {password: $scope.password, username: $scope.username}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // data is result with html format 
        return data
      });
  };
}
```

Then also make sure that you call this function so it actually runs!

`$scope.login()`. Alternatively, you may wanna make it call itself by using a self-invoking function, `(function() { /* your code */ })()`

Since you are writing HTML to a template, you might also need to use `ng-bind` and the `$sce` service [`trustAsHTML`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce#trustAsHtml)